# JavaScript new Function expression and new Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, new-operator

My question is regarding the resulting object from using `new function(){ ... }` over `new Function();`

**My understanding so far/assumption**

- When we create a function using Function() or new Function() we get a object configured as a function (it's internal slots indicate a function type object)
- With or without the new operator, the Function() constructor returns a new function object
- Using a function expression returns a function object which internally uses the Function() constructor
- A function expression provides optimization with parsing the function body

**My question**

Following my assumption above, why does `new Function();` and `new function(){ ... }` return different things?

The first returns a function object, but the latter returns a standard object. Given that a function expression under the hood uses the Function() constructor, why does the latter not behave the same as `new Function();`?

Using `new function(){ ...}` I would expect a function object, not a standard object.

Comment: `function(){} == new Function()`, `new function () {} == new new Function()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines are essentially the same:

```
function foo(...) {...}
var foo = function (...) {...};
var foo = new Function (...);
```

They all declare a new function (which is an object, that is an instance of `Function`, which inherits the `Object` prototype, ...) in the current scope which can be accessed via the `foo` variable.

The `new` keyword instantiates an object from a function which allows you to create something similar to a class instance in a standard OOP language.

Continuing the example from above:

```
var bar = new foo(...)
```

would instantiate an instance of the `foo` function in the current scope which could be accessed via the `bar` variable.

> why does `new Function();` and `new function(){ ... }` return different things?

---

I'm going to rephrase the example slightly. Instead of:

```
new Function()
//and
new function(){ ... }
```

I'm going to use

```
new Function()
//and
var foo = function () { ... };
new foo();
```

---

The reason that `new Function()` returns a different thing than `new foo()` is entirely because `Function` is a different function from `foo`.

I expect that you're not confused by the fact that `new Object()` returns a different object with different features than `new Array()`. The exact same thing is happening here.

> Given that a function expression under the hood uses the `Function()` constructor, why does the latter not behave the same as `new Function();`?

under the hood the later expression is essentially:

```
new (new Function ( ... ))
```

Answer (score 1):

new Function(...) returns a new **function**, while new function() {...} returns a new **Object**.

Basically, Function is just a way to evaluate a piece of code.

Objects are a way, to store data in javascript.

Side note: you can technically do

```
new (new Function(...))
```

wich returns a new object.